# looping through csv file to create numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working on a machine learning dataset, where each row in the csv represent an image with dimension 28*28:

```
row[0]=image label
row[1:]=information about pixel in the image
```

I need to loop through the CSV file to create 2 np array, 1 containing the label and the 2nd one containing the image.
The image array need to be a 3d numpy array.

```
csv_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
images = np.empty((0,28,28),dtype=np.float64)
labels = np.empty((0,1),dtype=np.float64)

for row in csv_reader:

  image= np.reshape(row[1:],(28,28))
  resize_image =image[np.newaxis,:]
  images = np.append(images,resize_image,axis=0)
  label = np.reshape(row[0],(1))
  resize_label = label[np.newaxis,:]
  labels = np.append(labels,resize_label,axis=0)

return images, labels
```

I feel like this is a really slow and not optimized method, is there any more efficient way to do the task?

Answer (score 0):

One solution example for this problem can be found here: [Digit Recognizer - CNN](https://www.kaggle.com/code/darkwyvern/digit-recognizer-cnn)

```
data_train = pd.read_csv(file)
x_train = data_train.drop(labels=["label"], axis=1)
y_train = data_train["label"]

x_train = x_train.values.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=10)
```

Comment: just curious, is there any other way not using pandas?